# SObject row was retrieved via SOQL without querying the requested field: Case.RecordType

Tags: apex, case, record-type, record

I am getting error on the below

```
 Map<Id,RecordType> caseMap = new Map<Id, RecordType>([SELECT Id, DeveloperName FROM RecordType WHERE SObjectType = 'Case']);
```

This is

```
Case cs : Trigger.New
```

I wanted to check something like

```
if(caseMap.get(cs.RecordTypeId).DeveloperName == 'XXX'){
 .....
.....
}
```

Error:

```
System.SObjectException: SObject row was retrieved via SOQL without querying the requested field: Case.RecordType
```

Comment: The error comes from the way you request your `cs` record.

Comment: I believe it will be helpful if you can post where the `cs` is coming from. If you are iterating over the list, can you share where the list is coming from.

Comment: Case cs : Trigger.New

Comment: I do belive that you should not get this error while iterating on Trigger.new. Are you sure that the error is from line number `caseMap.get(cs.RecordTypeId).DeveloperName` ?

Comment: This shouldn't be happening for records in Trigger.new list. Can you post other parts of the code where you are referencing RecordTypeId?

Comment: The error says that "RecordType" was not queried, not "RecordTypeId". Odds are, you have a typo in your code somewhere.